# Cut a UIImage into a circle

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I want to cut a `UIImage` into a circle so that I can then use it as an annotation. Every answer on this site that I've found describes creating an `UIImageView`, then modifying that and displaying it, but you cant set the image of an annotation to an `UIImageView`, only a `UIImage`.
How should I go about this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make sure to import QuarzCore if needed.

```
 func maskRoundedImage(image: UIImage, radius: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let layer = imageView.layer
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return roundedImage!
    }
```

Comment: Well I thought it would, I just checked it and I've imported QuartzCore and everything, doesnt round the image. Could you check if it works for you?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it in a playground.

Comment: Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)` if you see aliasing image.

Comment: Thanks much! Simple & FUNCTIONING answer!

Comment: I think this code is unnecessarily complicated. Instead of creating an unused image view, you can render into the image context directly with a clipping path.

Answer (score 109):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1 or later**

edit/update: For iOS10+ We can use UIGraphicsImageRenderer. For older Swift syntax check edit history.

```
extension UIImage {
    var isPortrait:  Bool    { size.height > size.width }
    var isLandscape: Bool    { size.width > size.height }
    var breadth:     CGFloat { min(size.width, size.height) }
    var breadthSize: CGSize  { .init(width: breadth, height: breadth) }
    var breadthRect: CGRect  { .init(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize) }
    var circleMasked: UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage?
            .cropping(to: .init(origin: .init(x: isLandscape ? ((size.width-size.height)/2).rounded(.down) : 0,
                                              y: isPortrait  ? ((size.height-size.width)/2).rounded(.down) : 0),
                                size: breadthSize)) else { return nil }
        let format = imageRendererFormat
        format.opaque = false
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: breadthSize, format: format).image { _ in
            UIBezierPath(ovalIn: breadthRect).addClip()
            UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: format.scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
            .draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize))
        }
    }
}
```

Playground Testing

```
let profilePicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
profilePicture.circleMasked
```

---

Comment: Great! Thanks. But if I add a border that is rather pixelated. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @LeoDabus. After choosing from gallery i need to crop an image. How can it possible

Comment: Using a `UIImageView` is overkill for this. See the Dmitry Coolerov solution that uses `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: @bcattle his method will distort images that are not squared

Comment: Somehow I had issues when choosing from library a picture with no orientation info (like taken with a camera). I had to implement a UIimage extension to fix the orientation first so all pictures (those taken with phone with orientation info and those not taken with phone) would work identically.

Comment: If you save your UIImage as PNG you will discard its orientation

Comment: You can save them as JPEG to include the media metadata (this will have its orientation as well) or check this post if you need PNG format https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098812/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus can we resize it and add a border to this mask as well? Is it possible to do it in a single `circleMasked` proprty?

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus And how to resize it to some size like I want the size to be 30 to be exacy

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 you are welcome. Note that you can also use a bezier path to mask a UIImageView https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805317/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried to resize it and then use to clip it with circle and border but it just cropped from the center and not gives me a whole image in `aspectFit`. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 What do you need UIImageView or UIImage? Do you need a fixed size (static) or do you want to be able to scale the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226540/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Note that the last link respects the image aspect ratio. It might be an elipse or a circle (is the image is squared)

Comment: @LeoDabus I want to scale it to a fixed size, So, that I can have a full logo regardless of cropping. Same that we got with aspectFit but just to add it with circle and border

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 better to open a new post with your attempt and the issues you are facing. The comments area are not meant for extended discussions.

Answer (score 10):

UIImage extension:

```swift
extension UIImage {

    func circularImage(size size: CGSize?) -> UIImage {
        let newSize = size ?? self.size

        let minEdge = min(newSize.height, newSize.width)
        let size = CGSize(width: minEdge, height: minEdge)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        self.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size), blendMode: .Copy, alpha: 1.0)

        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Copy)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)

        let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        rectPath.appendPath(circlePath)
        rectPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        rectPath.fill()

        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return result
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

UIImageView:

```swift
@IBDesignable class CircularImageView: UIImageView {

    override var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            super.image = image?.circularImage(size: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

UIButton:

```swift
@IBDesignable class CircularImageButton: UIButton {

    override func setImage(image: UIImage?, forState state: UIControlState) {
        let circularImage = image?.circularImage(size: nil)
        super.setImage(circularImage, forState: state)
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to set circle image for UIImageView with `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` and this answer works great

Answer (score 3):

Based on Nikos answer:

```
public extension UIImage {

func roundedImage() -> UIImage {
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: self)
    let layer = imageView.layer
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return roundedImage!
    }

}

//Usage

let roundedImage = image.roundedImage()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to circle Image

```
extension UIImage {
func circleImage(_ cornerRadius: CGFloat, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        var path: UIBezierPath
        if size.height == size.width {
            if cornerRadius == size.width/2 {
                path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2.0*CGFloat(Double.pi), clockwise: true)
            }else {
                path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
            }
        }else {
            path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        }
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context.clip()
        self.draw(in: rect)
        // 从上下文上获取剪裁后的照片
        guard let uncompressedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return nil
        }
        // 关闭上下文
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return uncompressedImage
    }else {
        return nil
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

All these answers were really complex for a straight forward solution.  I just replicated my Objective-C code and adjusted for Swift.

```
self.myImageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.myImageView?.frame.size.width)! / 2;
self.myImageView?.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Working with the layer corner radius can lead to dropped frames / performance problems if you have a lot of those items. That's why there are more complex and alternative solutions

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer my own question by finding a use of BezierPath!

```
if let xyz = UIImage(contentsOfFile: readPath) {
     var Rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, xyz.size.width, xyz.size.height)
     var x = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: Rect, cornerRadius: 200).addClip()

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(xyz.size, false, xyz.scale)
     xyz.drawInRect(Rect)
     var ImageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     annotation.image = ImageNew
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 8.1, Swift 3.0.1**

My code will look like this:

```
let image = yourImage.resize(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))?.circled(forRadius: 20)
```

Add UIImage Extension, then:

```
func resize(_ size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    return redraw(in: rect)
}

func redraw(in rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }

    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: rect.size.height)

    context.concatenate(flipVertical)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

func circled(forRadius radius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let rediusSize = CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }

    let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: rect.size.height)
    context.concatenate(flipVertical)

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: [.allCorners], cornerRadii: rediusSize)
    context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
    context.clip()

    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: I was seaching for code that to crop image as a circle And i found this Answer the best!, But there's a problem the image is Inverted how to fix that?

Comment: Could you help please?

Comment: Hi @Salah, I'm sorry that my previous methods have some problems. I have fixed that in my code now and you can try it! But although I have to write `circled(:)` method, but I rarely use it. Mostly `resize` +` fill(with:)` methods will help me to control my asset images, and I recommend you `Kingfisher`, he has to provide` RoundCornerImageProcessor `this class to do picture cropping function. You can see that in [here(https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Sources/ImageProcessor.swift)].

Comment: @Salah I write a glist to show all my image helpers. I am very welcome with you to study iOS development. You can see that in gist.github.com/YueJun1991/867f667f5a14eb65deaacf9db2120481

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate that its really helpful, I used your new redraw and circled but the image still inverted it looks like this: https://i.gyazo.com/9247d984e477cf77ad5bb5fbe5eba2b0.png why is that happening? I couldn't fix it

Comment: Do you know why the image inverted? or should i ask a question

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift 5.3, Xcode 12.2, Handles all imageOrientations

Based on answer [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29047372/12178476)

Thanks, works perfectly! BUT only for images with imageOrientation *.up* or *.down*. For images with *.right* or *.left* orientation there are distortions in result. And from iPhone/iPad camera for original photos initially we get *.right* orientation.

Code below takes into account imageOrientation property:

```
extension UIImage {

    func cropToCircle() -> UIImage? {
    
        let isLandscape = size.width > size.height
        let isUpOrDownImageOrientation = [0,1,4,5].contains(imageOrientation.rawValue)
    
        let breadth: CGFloat = min(size.width, size.height)
        let breadthSize = CGSize(width: breadth, height: breadth)
        let breadthRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize)
    
        let xOriginPoint = CGFloat(isLandscape ?
                                (isUpOrDownImageOrientation ? ((size.width-size.height)/2).rounded(.down) : 0) :
                                (isUpOrDownImageOrientation ? 0 : ((size.height-size.width)/2).rounded(.down)))
        let yOriginPoint = CGFloat(isLandscape ?
                                (isUpOrDownImageOrientation ? 0 : ((size.width-size.height)/2).rounded(.down)) :
                                (isUpOrDownImageOrientation ? ((size.height-size.width)/2).rounded(.down) : 0))
    
        guard let cgImage = cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xOriginPoint, y: yOriginPoint),
                                                     size: breadthSize)) else { return nil }
        let format = imageRendererFormat
        format.opaque = false
    
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: breadthSize, format: format).image {_ in
            UIBezierPath(ovalIn: breadthRect).addClip()
            UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: format.scale, orientation: imageOrientation).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3 conform to MVC pattern
create an external file

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundImage: UIImageView{


@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet{
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}

// set border width
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet{
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

// set border color

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet{
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}


}// class
```

call class in the IB on storyboard

[image: call class in the IB on storyboard]

set cornerradius as you please (1/2 of width if desire circle)

[image: set attribute]

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I am using RoundedImageView class, the problem facing is that when browse image from gallery the image not show in round or circle.. I simply change the  properties of UIImageView/RoundedImageView -> view -> Content Mode -> Aspect Fill[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVkL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @Leo Dabus is good but here's a better approach ✅

```swift
import UIKit

public extension UIImage {
    /// Returns a circle image with diameter, color and optional padding
    class func circle(_ color: UIColor, diameter: CGFloat, padding: CGFloat = .zero) -> UIImage {
        let rectangle = CGSize(width: diameter + padding * 2, height: diameter + padding * 2)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rectangle).image { context in
            let rect = CGRect(x: padding, y: padding, width: diameter + padding, height: diameter + padding)
            color.setFill()
            UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).fill()
        }
    }
}
```

##### How to use

```swift
let image = UIImage.circle(.black, diameter: 8.0)
```

- Fewer code lines
- Ability to add padding
- Non-optional result

Comment: So...this doesn't actually draw the image, just generates a colored circle?

Comment: @mackworth Yes, this matches the single responsibility principle. Then you can use the generated UIImageView to apply a mask or whatever the purpose you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The goal seems to be able to go from any picture to circular profile pictures for the screen. I started with @Leo Dabus excellent answer, but it didn't handle orientation or scaling and going through CGImage and cropping before the clipping seemed unnecessary. So I rewrote with UIImage.draw(). It handles scaling either by percentage or to a fixed size.

Note that it sets the resulting image scale to 3.0 to maintain as much picture quality as possible in the given size on the screen, regardless of the scale of the original image.

```
import UIKit

@objc
extension UIImage {
    
    var isPortrait:  Bool {return size.height > size.width }
    var isLandscape: Bool {return size.width  > size.height}
    
    func circleMask (breadth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        guard breadth > 0, size.width > 0, size.height > 0 else {return UIImage()}
        let scaleUp       = breadth / min(size.width, size.height)
        let breadthSize   = CGSize(width: breadth, height: breadth) 
        let breadthRect   = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize)
        let excessPoints  = (scaleUp * abs(size.width-size.height)/2).rounded(.down)
        
        let scaledSize = CGSize(width: size.width*scaleUp, height: size.height * scaleUp)
        let cropRect = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(
                x: isLandscape ? -excessPoints : 0,
                y: isPortrait  ? 0             : -excessPoints),
            size: scaledSize)
        
        let format = imageRendererFormat
        format.opaque = false
        format.scale = 3.0
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: breadthSize, format: format).image { _ in
            UIBezierPath(ovalIn: breadthRect).addClip()
            self.draw(in: cropRect)
        }
    }
    
    func circleMask(scaleUp: CGFloat = 1.0 ) -> UIImage {
        return circleMask(breadth: scaleUp * min(size.width,size.height))
    }
}
```

Sample call:

```
func profilePict(at loc: String) -> UIImage? {
    guard let url = URL(string:loc) else { print ("Bad URL: \(loc)"); return nil }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url) 
        let profilePicture = UIImage(data: data)
        if let profilePicture {
            return profilePicture.circleMask(breadth:80)
//          return profilePicture.circleMask(scaleUp:0.5)
        } else {
            print("Invalid data for image at \(loc)")
            return nil
        }
    }
    catch { print("No data at \(url) error: \(error)") }
    return nil
}   
    
    
profilePict(at: "https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/blob/219294e144531b0c01247913cb58b6f5531b5081/Landscape_7.jpg?raw=true")
```