# Rounded corners clipped in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to round the corners on my UIImageView in tableViewCells, however, for some reason, they are clipped. I have tried this:

```
cell.characterThumbnail.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.characterThumbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 15
```

and this is the result I get:

[image: ![Screenshot showing clipped rounded corners of UIImageView]

If I use the debug 3D viewer I get the frame is larger than I've set (I want 84 * 84 but it shows 84 * 110). Shown here:

[image: Screenshot showing debug frame at 84 * 110]

Why are there different sizes? And why are the rounded corners clipped? I have to point out that the image in the UIImageView is downloaded from an URL for each thumbnail.

Any help on this matter is much appreciated. It has bugged me for a week lol.

P.S. I forgot to mention that I've read almost every single "rounded corner" question here on SO and elsewhere on the internet, but no mention of clipped corners. Also, I have thought about rounding the actual image before displaying it in the UIImageView, but that makes the tableView scrolling jerky.

Edit: Whole project at https://github.com/Aecasorg/WoWilvlChecker

Comment: imageview  clipsToBound ?

Comment: set **cell. characterThumbnail. clipsToBound = true**

Comment: Try to implement this behaviour in an example project (with bundled images). I think you have a complex of errors here.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Yup, tried that before. No difference.

Comment: You can the put example project to GitHub and someone can look at it

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Here is the whole project: [https://github.com/Aecasorg/WoWilvlChecker] I've also now added the link to the above question.

Comment: Clips to bound should work, Are you adding shadow  or border s ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No borders, nor shadows. I want it simple. The rounded corners are there, but they are "clipped".

Comment: If the thumbnails are 84 x 84, but your imageView frame is 84 x 110, you need to set `aspectFill`, not `aspectFit`. This will then completely fill the frame. See answer below.

Comment: can't build your example "SwipeCellKit" is unavailable. Also, direct link is not correct.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I'm sorting it now and updating it. Give me a couple of mins...

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Ok, I'm currently uploading all updated pods to the GitHub repo. It'll be another 20 mins before that's finished (slow uplink).

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Ok, all updated.

Comment: The github project is not accessible.

Comment: Sorry, the correct link should be: https://github.com/Aecasorg/WoWilvlChecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all due to constraints. All I needed was to get rid of the "Leading Space to: Superview" and "Bottom View to: Superview" constraints I had set up and add an "Align Center Y to: Superview" and that sorted it. Thanks to everyone for responses and suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your image views are set to 'aspectFit', not aspectFill:

[image]

Comment: I changed it to AspectFill in Storyboards and I have clipsToBounds, but no difference. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set clipsToBounds true and give it a desired radius.

```
cell.image.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.image.clipsToBounds = true

//Use this to add border 

cell.image.layer.borderWidth = 3
cell.image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem what see is that round corner is getting drawn on 84X110 and not 84X84. That's why it looks strange.

Please call `sizeToFit()` (this resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.).

```
cell.characterThumbnail.sizeToFit()
cell.characterThumbnail.clipsToBound = true
```

just before

```
cell.characterThumbnail.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.characterThumbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 15
```

However, if you want to keep thumbnail-view fixed 84X84 and resize the image then you need to set `aspectFill`.
And in the storyboard of ([WoWilvlChecker](https://github.com/Aecasorg/WoWilvlChecker)) fix the width and height of the view to 84X84

Also I think cornerRadius not needed to be 15. A value like 3-5 should be sufficient.

Comment: I just tried putting `cell.characterThumbnail.sizeToFit()` before the above but no difference unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: Please also add  cell. characterThumbnail. clipsToBound = true. I hope that helps.

Comment: When you call sizeToFit(). Is view getting resized to 84X84 (equal to image size) OR it remains 84X110 ? The problem what see is that round corner is getting drawn but on 84X110 and not 84X84. That's why it looks strange

Comment: They remain 84x110. The whole project is here: [https://github.com/Aecasorg/WoWilvlChecker]

Comment: 84X110 is the actual issue. I will look in to github link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180420/discussion-between-rizwan-and-aecasorg).

Answer (score 1):

I checked your repo.

Remove centerY constraint, it seems centerY is causing this "stretched height" problem.

If you want to make imageView's Size applied,

then set width, height, (centerX, CenterY) or (vertical one, horizontal one)

Comment: Great! We're getting somewhere! Now I have the rounded corners but it is offset down. Just need to work out how to centre the UIImageView in the cell. Not quite sure how to apply the size as per your suggestion.

Comment: You can do in many ways, I would do in this way.
1. Keep centerY to leftLabel (Sorry for confusion)
2. Remove bottom to leftLabel
3. Remove imageView's leading to leftLabel + offset
4. Make centerX to leftLabel + offset + (imageWidth/2)

Comment: More specificaly, you had a "stretched height" problem because of two constraints, centerY and bottom to left label. With these two combined, constraint maker calculates imageView's top anchor which equals to leftLabel's top anchor, making same height with leftLabel.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll look at this once I get back tonight. I’ll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, it was due to constraints. All I needed was to get rid of the Leading Space to: Superview and Bottom View to: Superview and add an Align Center Y to: Superview and that sorted it (thanks again @Andrew Romanov for pull request).

Answer (score 1):

Project has problems with layout constraints and content mode in the imageView.
Just add height constraint for the imageView and change content mode to Aspect fill.
Also I recommend to use smaller corner radius, for example 5.0.  You can exam my changes in the pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the pull request! Much appreciated!