# How to Circle the image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Hello I am using **SDWebImage** in my app. This is my code to make the image in circle

```
extension UIImage {
var circle: UIImage? {
        let square = CGSize(width: min(size.width, size.height), height: min(size.width, size.height))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = self
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        imageView.layer.renderInContext(context)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
}
```

copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046571/cut-a-uiimage-into-a-circle-swiftios)

I used to do images in cicle like this

```
let profilePicture = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!)!

profilePicture.circle
```

But Now As I am using SDWebImage its not working

```
 cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(profileImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "default-profile-icon")?.circle!)
```

Please let me know how can I make this extension work for SDWebImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SDWebImageManager` to download the image or take it from the cache and apply the circle in the completion block like this:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadWithURL(NSURL(string:"img"), options: [], progress: nil) { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, finished:Bool) -> Void in
    if (image != nil){
        let circleImage = image.circle
        cell.profileImageView.image = circleImage
    }
}
```

Or you can use the version of the  `sd_setImageWithURL` method that takes a completion block as a parameter

```
let completionBlock: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
    if (image != nil){
        let circleImage = image.circle
        cell.profileImageView.image = circleImage
    }
}
cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(profileImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "default-profile-icon")?.circle!, completed: completionBlock)
```

Comment: Dude YOU ARE AWESOME BIGTIME. to be honest after not getting a answer after an hour I thought I never be able to use this extenion. YOU ARE GREAT. THANKS THANKS THANK BIG TIME