# Swift - Get a Circular Image in Spotlight Search (i.e. in the thumbnail)

Tags: ios, uiimage, corespotlight, uiimagejpegrepresentation

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to go about cropping the image that appears in the spotlight search, so that 'thumbnailData' is a circular image not a square one?

[image: This is taken from RayWenderlich.com]

None of these solutions work to the desired effect: [Cut a UIImage into a circle Swift(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046571/cut-a-uiimage-into-a-circle-swiftios)

I can successfully crop the image but then spotlight feature puts a white background around the cropped/masked border. It's possible with spotlight contacts (kUTTypeContact), just not content from what I can see (kUTTypeContent).

Here is my code for any boffins out there to take a peek:

```
    // For storing attributes into Searchable Dictionary
    internal var attributeSet: CSSearchableItemAttributeSet {
    let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeContent as String)
    attributeSet.title = "\(firstName) \(surname)"
    attributeSet.contentDescription = location
    attributeSet.keywords = ["tennis", "scorelord", firstName, surname, handed, location, "\(itnLevel)"]
    attributeSet.thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.8)
    attributeSet.thumbnailData?.displayLayer(<#T##layer: CALayer##CALayer#>)
    return attributeSet
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue as well.

Assuming your image has a transparent background, what worked for me was

```
 attributeSet.thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage)
```