# Rounding corners of images in an array xcode

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I'm attempting to round the corners of images that are stored within an array, but i'm not entirely sure if its possible?

```
 var holeImages = [UIImage(named:"1.png"),UIImage(named:"2.png"),UIImage(named:"3.png")] 

 self.holeImages1.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29047372/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to just apply a corner radius to the `layer` of the `UIImageView` in which you present the images, rather than rounding the images themselves, e.g.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

But if you really want to round the images, themselves, rather than rounding the `UIImageView` in which you present the images, you could also build a new array of rounded images from your `holeImages` array:

```
let roundedHoleImages = holeImages.map { return $0?.rounded(cornerRadius: 10) }
```

Where you could round the images with something like:

```
extension UIImage {

    /// Round the corners of an image
    ///
    /// - parameter cornerRadius: The `CGFloat` corner radius to apply to the images.
    ///
    /// - returns: The rounded image.

    func rounded(cornerRadius cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath)
        CGContextClip(context)
        drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return outputImage
    }

}
```

You might use this rounding of the actual images if you were, for example, uploading the images to some web service and you wanted to upload images with rounded corners. But, if not, rounding the image views is not only easier, but avoids problems resulting from images of different scales (especially if those scales are different from the display `scale`) as well as minimizing the memory impact of creating a separate array of images.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. If you wish apply some method of object for all objects in array, you should do this in cycle, since `Array` type most likely don't have this method:

```
for image in holeImages {
    image.performSomeMethod()
}
```

Also you can write `Array` extension to teach `Array` of objects (`UIImage` for example) for this method:

```
extension Array where Element: UIImage {
    func performSomeMethod() {
        for element in self {
            element.performSomeMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can do

```
holeImages.performSomeMethod()
```

But let's return to your case. `UIImage` type don't have property called `layer`; moreover, idea rounding corners of *image* looks strange without context. Usually you need to round corners when you present image on screen, and you usually use `UIImageView` container for this. So, you probably better round corners of this container instead images:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = holeImages.first
```