# Swift PNG Image being saved with incorrect orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, png, uiimagepickercontroller

If I use the image before it is saved it is normal. But if I save it and use it later is is 90 degrees turned.  How can I make sure it doesn't save sideways?

```
func saveEvent(_ center1: CLLocation, title2: String, imagePicked1: UIImage)
    {
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePicked1);///
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString+".dat")
        do {
            try data!.write(to: url!, options: [])
        } catch let e as NSError {
            print("Error! \(e)");
            return
        }
        let image11 = CKAsset(fileURL: url!)

        self.eventRecord.setObject(image11 as CKAsset, forKey: "Picture")
        let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData.save(self.eventRecord, completionHandler: { record, error in
                if error == nil
                {
                    print("Image saved")
                }else{
                    print(error!)
                }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Just use JPEG and your rotation will be fine

Comment: how can I do that @LeoDabus

Comment: yes or save it as JPEG @LeoDabus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi/29726675#29726675

Comment: JPEG worked well thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to save your PNG with correct rotation you will need to redraw your image if its orientation it is not `.up`. You can redraw it as follow:

```
extension UIImage {
    func png(isOpaque: Bool = true) -> Data? { flattened(isOpaque: isOpaque)?.pngData() }
    func flattened(isOpaque: Bool = true) -> UIImage? {
        if imageOrientation == .up { return self }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, isOpaque, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

edit/update:

For iOS10+ tvOS10+ you can use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`:

```
extension UIImage {
    func png(isOpaque: Bool = true) -> Data? { flattened(isOpaque: isOpaque).pngData() }
    func flattened(isOpaque: Bool = true) -> UIImage {
        if imageOrientation == .up { return self }
        let format = imageRendererFormat
        format.opaque = isOpaque
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in draw(at: .zero) }
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

Usage for images without transparency:

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/varL9.jpg")!))!

if let data = image.png() {
    let imageFromPNGData = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

---

With transparency :

```
if let data = image.png(isOpaque: false) {
    let imageFromPNGData = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, I searched for days. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is amazing, but I'm having a job converting this flattened data back to a UIImage with UIImage(data: . This method seems to reject the png data. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: @GeoffH This is a new image context. You can save it as JPEG or PNG. Feel free to open a new question with a minimum verifiable example I will take a look at it if you wish

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as well to prevent it from changing of orientation.

```
func rotateImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.up ) {
        return image
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
    let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return copy
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the image to JPEG data instead. No need to redraw your image:

`let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)`