# How to convert Data received from UIImagePNGRepresentation() to String and vice versa?

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I create `Data` from `UIImage`:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

And then I need to convert it to `String`;

```
    if let data = data {
        let stringFromData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
```

but `stringFromData` is nil. Why?

Comment: why did you get string instead of image ?

Comment: use this if you want image reverse back :let image : UIImage = UIImage(data: data)

Comment: I need to pass imageData when sharing some info using Branch.io for Universal Links.

Comment: The dictionary can contains only Strings...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Not regarding the question but if you save your image data as png it will not save the image orientation and it is uncompressed data. The easiest solution is to use jpeg or if the size doesn't matter you can flatten your png image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098390/swift-png-image-being-saved-with-incorrect-orientation/42098812#42098812

Answer (score 4):

You can get it using the Data method base64EncodedString()

```
if let data = data {
    let stringFromData = data.base64EncodedString()
    //  to decode base 64 string you can use Data base64Encoded String initializer
    if let dataFromBase64 = Data(base64Encoded: stringFromData) {
        print(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Your image data in Base64 string

For Encode

```
let stringFromData : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

And decode

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
```

Comment: how do I get `strBase64`?

Comment: check i have put both method