# UIImage sometimes flipped

Tags: swift

I am storing images in an SQLite database as base64Strings and using the following to decode the images again:

```
let dataDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: imageString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
let decodedImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded!)!

imageView.image = decodedImage
```

For some images, this works, but others are shown flipped vertically. Can anyone see a reason why it only works for some?

TIA

EDIT: How the image was encoded:

```
let imageEncoding = userImage.pngData()!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

For images, I just used the default ones in the simulator

Comment: @matt hopefully the update helps

Comment: Are you sometimes encoding images from your assets?

Comment: @Sulthan what do you mean by that?

Comment: @matt I'm not sure how to access where the default simulator images are saved

Comment: @matt `userImage = imageView.image!` after an image has been selected by the user. I'm not sure what other details there are to give, seeing as I do not know where the images provided in the default photo library in the simulator are stored

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098390/swift-png-image-being-saved-with-incorrect-orientation/42098812