# SwiftUI certain images being rotated 180 degrees after saving as pngdata

Tags: swiftui, uiimage, orientation

I am trying to create a SwiftUI app that, in one of its functions, saves an image as its pngdata to a class.

```
class Coupon: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var data: [String]
    var date: Date
    var image: Data
    init(name: String, date: String, dateobject: Date, image: UIImage, description: String) {
        self.data = [name, date, description]
        self.date = dateobject
        self.image = image.pngData()!
}
    static func == (one: Coupon, two: Coupon) -> Bool {
        return one.data == two.data && one.date == two.date
}
}
```

But whenever I display the image, like this:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: coupon.image))
```

Certain images get rotated upside down.

I've looked in many different answers, but none seem to solve my problem.

Why is this happening, and how do I solve it?

Comment: check out if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098812/3585796

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem by digging around. The problem was that I was saving  the `UIImage` as `pngdata`, which makes some images get a simpler new orientation. By simply saving it as `jpegdata`, by doing this:

```
self.image = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) ?? Data()
```

I was able to save the orientation, save some space (because JPEGs are smaller), and save my app!

Comment: The issue is that PNG has no metadata, therefore when you save the image representation as PNG you are discarding its orientation information. JPEG does have metadata and it keeps its orientation information when you save its image representation along with its metadata.