# Uploading Image in CoreData BinaryData Component, But While Fetching Image i Got Upside Down Image Problem

Tags: swift, core-data, uikit

My coredata components are like

and

My code For Upload And Fetch Data

i'm facing problem while getting image from coredata
as image is showing upside down while setting up in screen.

while uploading it's perfect as it is.

i'm using CoreData default , with manual class generating method.

```
@NSManaged public var id: UUID?
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var desc: String?
@NSManaged public var img: Data?
@NSManaged public var time: Date?
@NSManaged public var audio: Data?

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! 
AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
 
func GetSimpleNotes() -> [Notes] {
    let arrList = [Notes]()
    do {
        let catchdata = try context.fetch(Notes.fetchRequest())as! [Notes]
        return catchdata
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return arrList
}
//MARK: Add PicPin
func AddSimpleNote(title: String, description: String, images: UIImage?, audio: URL?, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let newNote = Notes(context: context)
    newNote.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
    newNote.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
    newNote.setValue(description, forKey: "desc")
    newNote.setValue(images?.pngData(), forKey: "img")
    
    newNote.setValue(Date(), forKey: "time")
    if let audio = audio, let audioData = try? Data(contentsOf: audio) {
        newNote.setValue(audioData, forKey: "audio")
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        completion("Note Added Successfully.")
    } catch {
        completion("Note Add Fail.")
    }
}
```

Comment: does this post help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68535322/swiftui-certain-images-being-rotated-180-degrees-after-saving-as-pngdata  or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098390/swift-png-image-being-saved-with-incorrect-orientation