# CIImage rectangular to square in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage

I need to convert a rectangular image into a square as shown in the picture. I know how to do this with UIImage, but how to do it with CIImage?

For UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {

    /// Represents a scaling mode
    enum ScalingMode {
        case aspectFill
        case aspectFit

        /// Calculates the aspect ratio between two sizes
        ///
        /// - parameters:
        ///     - size:      the first size used to calculate the ratio
        ///     - otherSize: the second size used to calculate the ratio
        ///
        /// - return: the aspect ratio between the two sizes
        func aspectRatio(between size: CGSize, and otherSize: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
            let aspectWidth  = size.width/otherSize.width
            let aspectHeight = size.height/otherSize.height

            switch self {
            case .aspectFill:
               return max(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            case .aspectFit:
                return min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            }
        }
    }

    /// Scales an image to fit within a bounds with a size governed by the passed size. Also keeps the aspect ratio.
    ///
    /// - parameter:
    ///     - newSize:     the size of the bounds the image must fit within.
    ///     - scalingMode: the desired scaling mode
    ///
    /// - returns: a new scaled image.
    func scaled(to newSize: CGSize, scalingMode: UIImage.ScalingMode = .aspectFill) -> UIImage {

        let aspectRatio = scalingMode.aspectRatio(between: newSize, and: size)

        /* Build the rectangle representing the area to be drawn */
        var scaledImageRect = CGRect.zero

        scaledImageRect.size.width  = size.width * aspectRatio
        scaledImageRect.size.height = size.height * aspectRatio
        scaledImageRect.origin.x    = 0//(newSize.width - size.width * aspectRatio) / 2.0
        scaledImageRect.origin.y    = 0//(newSize.height - size.height * aspectRatio) / 2.0

        /* Draw and retrieve the scaled image */
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

        draw(in: scaledImageRect)
        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return scaledImage!
    }
}
```

[IMAGE](https://photos.app.goo.gl/aGyUWVjPk7gPqC7BA)

Using composited () is too complicated. I suspect that clampedtoextent () should be used

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441918/2303865

Comment: Leo, it is UIImage. I need CIImage.Otherwise, I have to convert and this is an additional cost