# UIImageView cornerRadius is not making it circle

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, swift4

I've a viewController that is presented inside a `UIView` as I'm using [CarbonKit](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit) to make tabs like android.

I've a `userProfileViewController` which I'm showing under one of the tabs and this has the `UIImageView` which I'm making trying to show in a circle by using this code:

```
self.userDisplayPic.layer.cornerRadius = self.userDisplayPic.frame.size.width / 2;
self.userDisplayPic.clipsToBounds = true
```

and the result is:
[image]

My guess is that it may be because of the autoresizing when presented inside a `UIView` might be compressing the design but other elements specially the update button seems fine. SO any suggestions how this can be fixed?

Comment: Try doing on main thread.

Comment: I think your image width and height are not same.

Comment: The problem is probably when you are execution this. If it is in `viewDidLoad` move it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or change your constraints

Comment: Another option is to create a new image to use in your image view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046571/cut-a-uiimage-into-a-circle-swiftios/29047372#29047372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `self.userDisplayPic`'s **height** and **width** are not same first make it same then below code will be worked for you.

```
self.userDisplayPic.layer.cornerRadius = self.userDisplayPic.frame.size.width / 2;
self.userDisplayPic.clipsToBounds = true
```

And write those code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear` method

Answer (score 6):

Try to set cornerRadius in viewWillLayoutSubviews, It'll use actual width for radius.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.userDisplayPic.layer.cornerRadius = self.userDisplayPic.frame.size.width / 2;
        self.userDisplayPic.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , it work for me. It took me several hours～

Answer (score 3):

Some time  `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` is required

Try this code

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    

        self.userDisplayPic.layer.cornerRadius = self.userDisplayPic.frame.size.width / 2;
        self.userDisplayPic.clipsToBounds = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.userDisplayPic.layer.cornerRadius = userDisplayPic.frame.height/2
 self.userDisplayPic.clipsToBounds = true
```