# image in getting compress in circular UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am working on a profile pic.

I have added an UIImageView (say userImageView) on the storyboard with aspect mode SCALE TO FILL & added below code in my swift file

```
self.userImageView.layer.borderWidth = 10
self.userImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
self.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImageView.frame.height/2
self.userImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

but when tried to add an image from camera or album, image is getting compressed.

I have also tried to resize the image but still, the image is getting compress.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set your `contentMode` to `aspectFill`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29047372/2303865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In story board content mode is aspect fill or fit and click the clips to bounds its help to fit the image in the image view bounds

Comment: FYI: "and click the clips to bounds" is the same as `self.userImageView.clipsToBounds = true` ;)