# How to make an ellipse/circular UIImage with transparent background?

Tags: swift, uiimage, transparent, uibezierpath, uigraphicsimagerenderer

This is the code I am using

```
extension UIImage {        
    var ellipseMasked: UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)

        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: imageRendererFormat)
            .image{ _ in
                UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).addClip()
                UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
            .draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the image I got

[image]

The background color is black. 
How can I make the background transparent?
I tried different ways but haven't made it work yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass UIImageView and mask its CALayer instead of clipping the image itself:

```
extension CAShapeLayer {
    convenience init(path: UIBezierPath) {
        self.init()
        self.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

---

```
class EllipsedView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.mask = CAShapeLayer(path: .init(ovalIn: bounds))
    }
}
```

---

```
let profilePicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
let iv = EllipsedView(image: profilePicture)
```

---

**edit/update**

If you need to clip the `UIImage` itself you can do it as follow:

```
extension UIImage {
    var ellipseMasked: UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(origin: .zero, size: size)).addClip()
        draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

For iOS10+ you can use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`.

```
extension UIImage {
    var ellipseMasked: UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        let format = imageRendererFormat
        format.opaque = false
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image{ _ in
            UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).addClip()
            draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let profilePicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
profilePicture.ellipseMasked
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, what I want is an UIImage, not an UIImageView. That UIImage may be passed to other users later.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you very much! 

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you very much! It works like a charming! I directly set imageRendererFormat.opaque = false, it didn't work. Can you also explain why it works when you use a temporary variable?

Comment: Check `imageRendererFormat`  declaration `var imageRendererFormat: UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat { get }` There is no set. It is immutable. You need to create an instance of it, change its property and pass it to `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` initializer

Comment: Before you ask me about declaring `format` as immutable. `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat`  is a `Class`. You don't need to declare it as variable to change its properties if they are mutable. You can check opaque declaration as well  `var opaque: Bool { get set }`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the explanation! You saved my day!

Comment: I just added a new feature to one of my projects with the help of this code. Thanks again! @LeoDabus
https://github.com/guoyingtao/Mantis/#credits

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions using SwiftUI.

This solution can be used to clip the image shape to a circle.

```
Image("imagename").resizable()
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .scaledToFit()
```

This solution can be used to get more of an eclipse or oval shape from the image.

```
Image("imagename").resizable()
    .cornerRadius(100)
    .scaledToFit()
    .padding()
```