# How to recognize the orientation of document(.pdf,.doc,.png) in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was going through our codebase and identified that we are not checking the orientation of documents during printing. It is automatically taking default orientation as Portrait, even when I am passing the landscape document.

So, I want to know, is there any function in Objective-C that helps me in recognizing the orientation of document while printing.

**Note: I am not talking about device orientation but the orientation of the document that has to be printed**

Comment: A PDF file has the orientation?  A Word file has it, too?

Comment: That's easy. You just need to get the page size. Btw if your question is about Objective-C why did you tag your question with Swift?

Comment: @ElTomato ,I didn't get you.
To be more specific I want to recognize the orientation of documents before printing.

Comment: For images you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/29047372/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus,
Thanks and I readjusted tags(PS: This is my first post that's why i did that,i will keep in mind for the next time)

Comment: For PDFs it is the same approach. Get the page dimensions and just check if the height is greater than the width is portrait otherwise is landscape.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that all pages in a PDF will have the same orientation.

Comment: @LeoDabus,got it thanks